# A calculation involving two circles

Tags: circles

I have two circles, one of which is completely within the other. They do not touch, but are not necessarily concentric. I am given the sum of their circumferences, and the difference in their areas (ie, the area of the space inside the outer circle and outside the inner circle). I need to find the average distance between the circles or, equivalently, the radii of the circles.

In other words, given $C = C_o + C_i$, and $A = A_o - A_i$, find $R_o$ and $R_i$.

I've gotten as far as expressing $A$ in terms of $C_o$ and $C_i$, but then my long-unused algebra fails me. Any help? Thanks...

Comment: What *is* the average distance between two non-concentric shapes, anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the area is $\pi r^2$ and circumference is $2\pi r.$
The sum of circumferences gives you equation:
$$ r_1 + r_2 = \frac{C}{2\pi}. \tag{1}$$
The difference of areas gives a second equation:
$$ r_1^2 - r_2^2 = \frac{A}{\pi}. \tag{2}$$
Factor LHS of $(2)$ into $(r_1 - r_2)(r_1 + r_2),$ substitute the value of $r_1 + r_2$ from $(1),$ and you will then have 2 linear equations in two unknowns, which you can solve.

Comment: Hint, the two equations are $$ r_1 + r_2 = \frac{C}{2\pi} \\
r_1 - r_2 = \frac{2A}{C}. $$ Add them up to solve for $r_1,$ then subtract or substitute to solve for $r_2.$

Comment: Finally, it's $$ R_o = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{C}{2\pi} + \frac{2A}{C} \right)\\ R_i = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{C}{2\pi} - \frac{2A}{C} \right). $$

Comment: Thanks; it's been a long time since I've used my algebra, but I was able to follow your answer for the most part. I got lost on the equation for r_1 - r_2 (which is really all I need). You came up with 2A/C but, following your instructions (factor LHS of (2), substitute RHS of (1)), I came up with (pi X A )/C. Could you double-check?

Comment: We have $$r_1^2 - r_2^2 = (r_1 + r_2)(r_1 - r_2) = \frac{A}{\pi}$$ and $$r_1 + r_2 = \frac{C}{2\pi}.$$ So $$\frac{C}{2\pi}(r_1 - r_2) = \frac{A}{\pi}.$$ Cancel the $\pi$'s from both sides, and move $\frac{C}{2}$ into the other side, we get $$r_1 - r_2 = \frac{2A}{C}.$$

Comment: @user36864 feel free to ask follow up questions.

Comment: It's a shame; I was really good at this stuff in high school. You really do lose it if you don't use it. Thanks so much for the help.